# Thread blocks the main thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, openstack-swift

I'm not `python` programmer.
But I need to write middleware for Openstack Swift. I don't know what environment the code running in. I have no control over the main thread.

I'm tyring to start sub-thread that will service the queue, but this thread blocks main thread.
The main thread prints `1` and hangs. Pressing Ctrl+C leads to contine execution, but sub-thread stops.

Where to dig?

```py
class ProxyLoggingMiddleware(object):
    """
    Middleware that logs Swift proxy requests in the swift log format.
    """

    def __init__(self, app, conf, logger=None):
        self.queue = Queue(0)
        print "1\n"
        self.processor = self.init_queue_processor()
        print "2\n"


    def init_queue_processor(self):
        processor = threading.Thread(target=self.process_queue, args=(self.fifo_pipe_pathname, self.queue, self.logger))
        processor.setDaemon(True)
        processor.start()
        return processor

    @staticmethod
    def process_queue(fifo_pipe_pathname, queue, logger):
        json_encoder = json.JSONEncoder()
        while True:
            stat = queue.get(True) # <----------------------- Blocks here
```

UPD:
I add next code in the middleware and it prints 1, 2, 3

```py
def m():
    print "--1\n"
    time.sleep(3)
    print "--2\n"


t = threading.Thread(target=m)
t.daemon = True
t.start()

print "--3\n"
```

But should 1 3 2

**THE PROBLEM OCCURS ONLY WHEN THIS CODE RUNS IN Openstack Swift environment!**

UPD2:

```sh
/opt/swift # python --version
Python 2.7.18
/opt/swift # uname -a
Linux 45cefc56fd0a 5.10.60.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Aug 25 23:20:18 UTC 2021 x86_64 Linux
```

UPD3:

I updated my code

```py
    def __init__(self, app, conf, logger=None):

        print threading.currentThread()
        self.processor = self.init_queue_processor()

    def init_queue_processor(self):
        processor = threading.Thread(target=self.process_queue, args=(self.fifo_pipe_pathname, self.queue, self.logger))
        processor.setDaemon(True)
        processor.start()
        return processor

    @staticmethod
    def process_queue(fifo_pipe_pathname, queue, logger):
        print threading.currentThread()
        json_encoder = json.JSONEncoder()
        while True: ....
```

The output is

```
/opt/swift # /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/swift-proxy-server /etc/swift/proxy-server.conf
<_MainThread(MainThread, started 140613464898888)>


<_MainThread(MainThread, started 140613464898888)>
```

I see `process_queue` executing in main thread.

Comment: try using multiprocessing ... basically `queue.get(False)` returns immediatly and then goes to while true ... effectively using 100% of this CPU ... alternatively you could use `queue.get(True)` i think... threading only will task switch in python if its thread control is yeilded (things like reading from disk etc) ... multiprocessing will use a second core, leveraging the OS level task switching control

Comment: @JoranBeasley it doesn't matter what's in the method, it blocks the main thread, even contains `time.sleep`. The main thread hangs on `thread.start()`, but shouldn't.

Comment: @hett you are correct that time.sleep() should release the GIL and allow task switching ... are you sure you see the same behaviour with time.sleep?

Comment: @JoranBeasley yep, I updated question with simple test with sleeps.

Comment: I think we need some extra information here. which version of python and which OS are you using?

Comment: @hett it works exactly right when i tested below in python3 i see both 1 and 2 when i run the below code  ... I can see you are using python2 from your print statements... maybe(possibly) i guess there is a bug in some older python(more likely "these are not the droids you are looking for"

Comment: ohh this is python 2.7 !  IIRC `time.sleep` pauses the entire *process* and not just the thread

Comment: @JoranBeasley please look my UPD3

Comment: @Nullman please look my UPD3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG, I found help in the Swift sources.
Openstack Swift uses green threads from `eventlet`.

It need to use another implementation of known classes

```
from eventlet import sleep
from eventlet.green import threading
```

instead of the standard python threading, because it patched, how I understod.

so it's explains why the `Main` thread using everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

A call to queue.get(False) will raise an Exception (Empty) if there are no data waiting on the queue.

There is no code shown that tries to handle that exception.

Therefore, as the exception is unhandled, the thread will terminate

Comment: [strike]this is not true[/strike] ...

Comment: Queue.get(block=True, timeout=None)
Remove and return an item from the queue. If optional args block is true and timeout is None (the default), block if necessary until an item is available. If timeout is a positive number, it blocks at most timeout seconds and raises the Empty exception if no item was available within that time. Otherwise (block is false), return an item if one is immediately available, else raise the Empty exception (timeout is ignored in that case).

Comment: opps, it was `get(True)`, I just updated it when trying to understand the problem.

Comment: I retract my earlier statement :P +1 you might be right

Comment: But it doesn't matter, problem persists event i replace all thread body on `time.sleep(100)`

Comment: If the code is *queue.get(True)* then it will block indefinitely. That's what it's supposed to do

Comment: meh it still works as expected in the example below(I deleted it because i think you might be more right) even if i make it `get(True)` ... so i still maintain his problem lies elsewhere

Comment: @ArthurKing please look my UPD3